# Jax WS WebService operation with two parameters Giveing Error while calling

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have a jax-ws webservice class with a operation having two web parameters.
I am trying to send a request to it but it is throwing exception that the expected JAXB elements did not received, I am using SOAP UI to send requests.

**Webservice class**

```
    @MTOM
    @WebService(endpointInterface = "com.carecentrix.service.ClaimService")
    public class ClaimServiceImpl implements ClaimService {

        @Resource
        public WebServiceContext context;

        private static Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        public String saveClaim(CCXClaim claim, CCXAttachment ccxAttachment) {
            String claimId = String.valueOf(dataMap.size()+1);
            if (!dataMap.containsKey(claimId)) {
                claim.getClaim().getHeaderInfo().get(0).getClaims().setClaimId(Long.valueOf(claimId));
                dataMap.put(claimId, claim);
            }
            System.out.println("claim object AppTransID" + dataMap);

            return claimId;
        }
    }
```

**SOAP UI Request**

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.carecentrix.com/" xmlns:cla="http://www.carecentrix.com/claim" xmlns:cla1="http://www.carecentrix.com/claimattachment">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ser:saveClaim>
             <!--Optional:-->

             <cla:CCXClaim schemaVersion="1.0">
                <cla:Claim>
                   <cla:AppTransID>12233</cla:AppTransID>
                   <cla:ClaimType>I</cla:ClaimType>

                   <cla:CreatedDate>2013-05-07</cla:CreatedDate>
                   <cla:CreatedBy>rrchapp</cla:CreatedBy>
                   <cla:CreatedByProcess>rrchapp</cla:CreatedByProcess>

                   <cla:HeaderInfo>
                      <cla:Claims>

                         <cla:ClaimHeaderId>1234444</cla:ClaimHeaderId>
                         <!--Optional:-->
                         <cla:ClaimSubmitionId>1</cla:ClaimSubmitionId>
                         <cla:CreatedBy>rrchapp</cla:CreatedBy>
                         <cla:CreatedDate>2013-05-27</cla:CreatedDate>
                         <!--Optional:-->
                         <cla:CreatedProcess>biztalk</cla:CreatedProcess>
                         <!--Optional:-->
                         <cla:SubmissionVersion>1</cla:SubmissionVersion>
                         <cla:UpdatedProcess>rrchapp</cla:UpdatedProcess>
                         <cla:UpdatedBy>rrchapp</cla:UpdatedBy>
                         <cla:UpdatedDate>2013-05-27</cla:UpdatedDate>
                         <cla:ClaimId>12344444555</cla:ClaimId>
                      </cla:Claims>

                   </cla:HeaderInfo>
                   <!--Optional:-->
                   <cla:TransactionId>233</cla:TransactionId>
                   <cla:TSCreateDate>2013-05-27</cla:TSCreateDate>
                   <!--Optional:-->
                   <cla:TSPurposeCode>899</cla:TSPurposeCode>
                   <cla:UpdatedDate>2013-05-27</cla:UpdatedDate>
                   <cla:UpdatedBy>rrchapp</cla:UpdatedBy>
                   <cla:UpdatedProcess>rrchapp</cla:UpdatedProcess>

                </cla:Claim>

               <cla:DocIdentifier>
                   <cla:SourceSystem>ABCD</cla:SourceSystem>
                   <cla:SourceApplication>ABCC</cla:SourceApplication>
                   <cla:DocCreateDate>2013-05-27</cla:DocCreateDate> 
                </cla:DocIdentifier>
             </cla:CCXClaim>


             <cla1:CCXAttachment>
                <cla1:ClaimAttachment>
                   <cla1:AttachmentContent>cid:821808624369</cla1:AttachmentContent>
                </cla1:ClaimAttachment>
             </cla1:CCXAttachment>

          </ser:saveClaim>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Error**

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soap:Body>
          <soap:Fault>
             <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
             <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.carecentrix.com/claim", local:"CCXClaim"). Expected elements are &lt;{}CCXClaim>,&lt;{}CCXAttachment></faultstring>
          </soap:Fault>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Above is the webservice method, class. request. I am having two parameters, but somehow
the service is throwing back the fault exception.
Please  help why this happening, Request is sent with correct namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that an `<CCXClaim>` element without namespace is expected. However, in your request `<cla:CCXClaim>` is obviously associated with the namespace URI `http://www.carecentrix.com/claim` through the `cla` prefix.

Since you didn't post your `WSDL` (and `XSD` if there even is one) it's hard to figure out. Try removing the `cla` and `cla1` prefixes in your request.